# Fail to create object using Intellij idea plugin API

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm creating a IntelliJ plugin & Want to acheive following.

- While doing a code in IntelliJ, if user right clicks in any Java file, I want to create a object of that class (Provided it is a valid class as per java specs).

Below is the code I tried to do the same.

```
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnActionEvent
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.CommonDataKeys
import com.intellij.openapi.editor.Editor
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project
import com.intellij.psi.PsiClass
import com.intellij.psi.PsiDocumentManager
import com.intellij.psi.util.PsiTreeUtil


class GenerateAction : AnAction() {
    override fun actionPerformed(e: AnActionEvent) {
        e.getData(CommonDataKeys.EDITOR)?.let {
            val clazz = getClass(it, e.project)
            if (clazz != null) {
                e.project?.let {  createObject(clazz) }
            }
        };
    }

    private fun createObject(psiClass: PsiClass){
        Class.forName(psiClass.qualifiedName);
    }


    fun getClass(editor: Editor, project: Project?): PsiClass? {
        val psiFile = PsiDocumentManager.getInstance(project!!).getPsiFile(editor.getDocument())
        val elementAtCaret = psiFile!!.findElementAt(editor.getCaretModel().getOffset())
        return PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType(
            elementAtCaret,
            PsiClass::class.java
        )
    }
}
```

When I tried to create a object it throws ClassNotFoundException. I tried multiple things including UrlClassLoader but no success.

Comment: The best place for IntelliJ IDEA plug-in development questions would be https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development.